# Native share popup on iOs positioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup

I'm creating native share popup on ios with this code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES3/gl.h>

using namespace share;

@interface ViewController:UIViewController
@end

//----------//----------//----------//----------//----------//----------//

@implementation ViewController

namespace share

{
    static ViewController *acController;

    BOOL shareSucceed;
    BOOL shareFailed;



    void shareWithFile(const char *subj, const char *msg, const char *filePath, const char *type)
    {
        acController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

        NSString *subject = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:subj];
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:msg];
        NSString *newFilePath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:filePath];
        NSURL *videoLink = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:newFilePath];

        NSArray* shareItems = @[message, videoLink];

        UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
        [avc setValue:subject forKey:@"subject"];

        NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeMessage];

        avc.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

        id VC = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder];


        NSLog(@"UiPopoverPresentationController for iPad IOS8");

        CGFloat width  = acController.view.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat height = acController.view.frame.size.height;

        NSLog(@"%.2f",width);
        NSLog(@"%.2f",height);

        avc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        avc.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = 0;
        avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(width, height ,1, 1);
        avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = acController.view;
        [VC presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    bool shareResultSucceed()
    {
        if (shareSucceed)
        {
            shareSucceed = NO;
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    bool shareResultFailed()
    {
        if (shareFailed)
        {
            shareFailed = NO;
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

@end
```

Popup is showing, but with different positioning on different devices. Looks like it totally ignores ...sourceRect = CGRectMake(width, height ,1, 1);
Why it ignores positioning rect?

Comment: isn't CGRectMake shold be (x,y,width,height) ? and not (width,height,x,y) ?

Comment: In addition to putting the `CGRectMake` parameters in the proper order, also note that the `sourceRect` should not be the whole view. It should be a small portion of it such as for a specific button or other widget.

Comment: tried using avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(200, 150, 300, 300);, but it's still on wrong position. Still no effect of sourceRect based positioning.